# Performance impacts of having multiple react bundles in the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, webpack

So I have a HTML page (the main page) which has references to 2 javascript bundles created by 2 different teams, say app1.js and app2.js.

```
<html>
<script src='path to app1.js'/>
<script src='path to app2.js' />
</html>
```

Both teams use react and react-dom.

It seems to be redundant to use react and react-dom in both of the bundles.

Can the production bundle of a single page app be created without react/react-dom in it so that the main page can look something like this?

```
<html>
<script src='path to react-cdn.js'/>
<script src='path to react-dom-cdn.js' />
<script src='path to app1.js without react/react-dom'/>
<script src='path to app2.js without react/react-dom' />
</html>
```

If both teams use separate versions of react/react-dom, will it cause version conflicts?

Please note:

1. The teams work separately in separate codebases.
2. I control the main page. But I don't have control over the teams. Meaning, I can't combine them into one.
3. They will need react and react-dom in their development environment.
4. Both teams use Webpack.

Comment: What development environment/IDE are you using? In my experience you never work with bundles directly, you generate them at compile/runtime as needed

Comment: I dont think thats necessary in all projects. It could very well be a PHP/JSP page which htmlwebpackplugin cannot generate at build time.

Comment: Then you can generate them dynamically at runtime which is how System.Web.Optimizations works in ASP.NET. Ultimately my point being that sharing pre-bundled files seems like a huge anti-pattern.

Comment: Well, the fact of the matter is, the mother page expects app1.js and app2.js to be there in a CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) for this.

We have a similar setup where there are multiple react bundles in the same page. So it didnt make sense to have react, react-dom, moment etc in every bundle.

You could try the following:

- Provide react and react-dom as global dependencies in the html page
- Have both the teams work on those versions of react and react-dom
- Use Webpack externals to omit react and react-dom from the production
  bundles.